# Unable to sync home directory in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

This is the code I tried

```
config.vm.synced_folder ENV['HOME'], "/home/vagrant/myHome", :mount_options => ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]


 config.vm.synced_folder "~", "/home/vagrant/myHome", :mount_options => ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]
```

Comment: Can you please show us what the error is like? :)

Comment: did you try the full path of the directory ? `config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/<name>", ...`

Comment: No Error. The directory is empty. @FrédéricHenri I tired complete path and it is working. My objective is to sync the home directory of the user who uses my vagrant box. So irrespective of username I need to sync the user's home with my vagrant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get the user's home directory using ruby directly - [`Dir.home`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-home)

```
config.vm.synced_folder "#{Dir.home}", "/home/vagrant/myHome" ...
```

should get the current user's directory (should work on Windows too)